# Ajax call inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a loop in my jQuery code. Inside the loop there is an AJAX call. Since for each loop an AJAX call to the server is fired, does it mean a new thread is created for each call at the server side? Do all calls get a new thread? This is my jQuery code for your reference:

```
function Run() {
  var i = 0;
  var r = '${result}'
  var par = '${paramy}'
  var str = r.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
  var resjson = JSON.parse(str);
  var parjson = JSON.parse(par);

  //loop to send ajax req multiple times. 
  for (var i = 0; i < resjson.length; i++) {
    var k = i + 1;
    var m = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(resjson[i]));
    var py = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(parjson));
    var pass = '';

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post', // it's easier to read GET request parameters
      url: 'servlet1',
      async: true,
      data: { 
        r: m,
        p:py
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("pass"`enter code here`)
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("fail"); 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of call one by one send as single call with JSON

Comment: Does the servlet clone itself on every ajax request?

Comment: @vinox, the requirement was such that I had to send the request one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since for each loop an AJAX call to the server is fired, does it mean a new thread is created for each call at the server side?

That depends entirely on the infrastructure being used on the server side.  Few servers would *create* a brand-new thread for each request but many would *assign* a thread from a pool to each request, and return that thread to the pool when the request is serviced.

Comment: Okay. Even though the thread allocated is form the existing pool, still the request will get one entire thread. right? Does the server clone itself for each request?

Comment: @Kritz -- servicing a request will almost always occupy a thread, however that thread is managed.  Read up on Node for example (which is actually single-threaded) or Apache (which has a master process managing child processes and each child process has a pool of threads).

Answer (score 0):

Each AJAX call creates a new XHR, no matters if it is called in a loop or not. If "async: false" that means jquery will wait till the request is completed/failed.